# Pasar por parámetro JSON Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Tengo el siguiente componente html al cual le paso un Json:

```
<a href="javascript:abreModal('{ 'name':'John', 'age':'30', 'city':'New York'}');">
     Pulsador
</a>
```

Y la función Javascript:

```
function abreModal(text) {
        //var text = '{ "name":"John", "age":"function () {return 30;}", "city":"New York"}';
        obj = JSON.parse(text);
        alert(obj.name);
}
```

El error que me lanza firebug es:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Sospecho que el error esta en las comillas del `abreModal(...)` he probado a cambiar las comillas sin resultado.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
abreModal('{ 'name':'John', 'age':'30', 'city':'New York'}');
          ^  ^
```

Tu cadena está entre las dos marcas que te puse, y lo siguiente que escribes es `name` en lugar de una coma (`,`) o el cierre del paréntesis. Lo que te recomiendo es que no mandes un Json sino el objeto:

```
<a href="javascript:abreModal({ 'name':'John', 'age':'30', 'city':'New York'});">
    Pulsador
</a>
```

Y así no es necesario parsear ni nada:

```
function abreModal(obj) {
    alert(obj.name);
}
```

Recuerda que Json sirve para intercambiar datos entre servidor y cliente, no tiene mucho sentido que transformes un objeto en Json y después lo parsees en el mismo script.

Ahora bien, si la situación es que recibes ese Json desde otro lado, entonces te recomiendo que lo parsees antes de mandarlo y mandes la variable que lo contenga.

Answer (score 4):

Simplemente remueve las comillas y pasa el *objeto* como tal, así puedes acceder directamente a el en la *función*, es decir:

Tu tienes esto:

```
javascript:abreModal('{ 'name':'John', 'age':'30', 'city':'New York'}');
                     ^                                               ^
```

Simplemente remueve las comillas que encierran el *objeto*

```
javascript:abreModal( { 'name':'John', 'age':'30', 'city':'New York'} );
                     ^                                               ^
```

Y ya no necesitas parsear nada pues tendrás un *objeto* literal con el cual trabajar y acceder a sus propiedades

```js
function abreModal(obj) {
  console.log('Name: ' + obj.name + ', Age: ' + obj.age + ', City: ' + obj.city)
  alert('Name: ' + obj.name + ', Age: ' + obj.age + ', City: ' + obj.city);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:abreModal({ 'name':'John', 'age':'30', 'city':'New York'});">
     Pulsador
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si realmente necesitas pasar **una cadena `JSON` por parámetro**, entonces:

Podrías imprimir el `JSON` encodeado para URI, de esta forma las comillas simples (`'`), dobles (`"`) y cualquier otro carácter especial quedarían escapados, evitando de esta forma que el HTML se rompa.

En `JS` puedes usar [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURI)

Ejemplo:

```js
function abreModal(text) {
  obj = JSON.parse(text);
  alert(obj.name);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:abreModal('%7B%22name%22%3A%22John%22%2C%22age%22%3A30%2C%22city%22%3A%22New%20York%22%7D');">
     Pulsador
</a>
```

Comment: Aunque es una respuesta válida, ¿no crees que sea poco legible?

Answer (score 0):

Una buena practica es usar `onclick`y tenias comillas simples por demas, el JSON que envias no hace falta parsear.

```js
function abreModal(text) {
        
        console.log(text.name);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="abreModal({'name':'John', 'age':'30'})">
     Pulsador
</a>
```